# Tkinter entry do not set the right width

Tags: python, tkinter

im trying to make a interface with tkinter, and i can't set the width of my entrys right

Even with the width as 20, the size of the last entry is wrong, someone can help me?

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucLua.png "Interface

```
ed1 = Entry(janela, width=20)
ed1.place(x=70, y=50)

ed2 = Entry(janela, width=20)
ed2.place(x=90, y=50)

ed3 = Entry(janela, width=20)
ed3.place(x=110, y=50)

ed4 = Entry(janela, width=20)
ed4.place(x=70, y=70)

ed5 = Entry(janela, width=20)
ed5.place(x=90, y=70)

ed6 = Entry(janela, width=20)
ed6.place(x=110, y=70)

bt = Button(janela,width=20, text="Somar", command=soma)
bt.place(x=70, y=150)

lb = Label(janela, text="Resultado")
lb.place(x=100, y=120)
janela.geometry("300x200+100+100")

janela.mainloop()
```

Comment: The size of the first two entries on each line is too short because of the overlap.  The size of the last entry is 4 times the size of `Somar`, which is 20 chars.  I do no see what problem you see.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why `place` is the wrong choice -- you have to do all the math yourself rather than letting tkinter do all of the computations. I recommend switching to `grid` or `pack`, which makes creating a row of entries extremely easy.

Answer (score 0):

The 20's unit in `width=20` is not equal to the number in `x=70` unit.
so your code can be modified into this：

```
ed1 = Entry(janela, width=5)
ed1.place(x=70, y=50)

ed2 = Entry(janela,width=5)
ed2.place(x=110, y=50)

ed3 = Entry(janela, width=5)
ed3.place(x=150, y=50)

ed4 = Entry(janela, width=5)
ed4.place(x=70, y=70)

ed5 = Entry(janela, width=5)
ed5.place(x=110, y=70)

ed6 = Entry(janela, width=5)
ed6.place(x=150, y=70)

bt = Button(janela,width=20, text="Somar", command=soma)
bt.place(x=70, y=150)

lb = Label(janela, text="Resultado")
lb.place(x=100, y=120)
lb.place(x=100, y=120)
janela.geometry("300x200+100+100")

janela.mainloop()
```